# Is there any way to clear all data stored from the installation of app?

Tags: ios, iphone, caching, nsuserdefaults, clear-cache

I have an iOS app which stores data in `NSUserDefults` and many other data is set in cache as a result of web view load, social media signing etc.
I want to remove all the data from cache created by the app.

Is there any way to do this programmatically in iOS?

Comment: this link already covers your question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460690/can-i-programmatically-wipe-the-application-data-in-applicationdidfinishlaunchin)

Answer (score 3):

You could try this

**NSUserDefaults**

```
  NSString *appDomain = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:appDomain];
```

or

```
NSUserDefaults * defs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDictionary * dict = [defs dictionaryRepresentation];
for (id key in dict) {
    [defs removeObjectForKey:key];
}
[defs synchronize];
```

**UIWebview Cache**

```
[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
```

//Delete cookies

```
 for(NSHTTPCookie *cookie in [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]) {

  if([[cookie domain] isEqualToString:someNSStringUrlDomain]) {

    [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] deleteCookie:cookie];
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 NSString *appDomain = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:appDomain];
```

or

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setPersistentDomain:[NSDictionary dictionary] forName:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"defunctPreference"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Some of the caches are connected with other apps' information. You should be careful when you delete them. Just remind you to check before operating. I have made the similar stupid mistakes before. If you have found a great tool. Please share! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];`

For more details, refer to link http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/104198-programmatically-clearing-app-cache.html

Comment: what if you try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15064854/delete-files-from-nscachesdirectory-programmatically) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `NSUserDefaults`, you may try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545091/clearing-nsuserdefaults).

In terms of other cache files, I think you should keep all of them in a folder, so that they can be removed easily by removing the whole cache folder.